# Flutter Federated Plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I am trying to develop a federated plugin which will wrap a native SDK (for android and ios) as explained [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin), and also went over the examples shown [here](https://medium.com/flutter/how-to-write-a-flutter-web-plugin-part-2-afdddb69ece6) and the [url_launcher plugin](https://github.com/hterkelsen/plugins/tree/url-launcher-platform/packages/url_launcher) example but nevertheless, I couldn't figure out a few things..

In the documentation there is no example of how to create **platform interface package**
and how it can be used in all platforms of the plugin (The example article and url_launcher shows the web plugin but none of ios and android of the example project uses the platform interface package) and it seems that these examples are old and not updated.

Also, they explain that a **platform package** should refer the **platform interface package** in it's pubspec.yaml with the **implements** definition like this:

```
flutter:
plugin:
  implements: hello //this refers to the platform interface package
platforms:
  windows:
    pluginClass: HelloPlugin
```

But I couldn't find any example about this, and how this **implements** comes in help and how the **platform-plugin** can use **platform-interface-package** like explained in the documentation

Is there any good and updated example or tutorial about this topic?

Comment: Very late response but for what it's worth, maybe check out [quick_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/quick_blue) follow a simple function call like `startScan`. There's the [quick_blue_platform_inteface](https://github.com/woodemi/quick_blue/tree/master/quick_blue_platform_interface) package, quick_blue, and then choose a specific native implementation, e.g. quick_blue_macos, an example of how to call it is in the example repo.

Comment: @David, Thanks for your comment. I've looked on their repo and in did it gives good example for plugin in flutter. Still I didn't saw any mention for using implement keyword in their yaml.

Comment: oh you're correct. Apologies. Maybe it's more optional than the documentation shows. [This](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/1598ccd896653cbe40b7401fb0eafd890e784b39/packages/image_picker/image_picker_windows/pubspec.yaml#L13) is a more common package and it seems the `implements` exists in each platform specific pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [flutter plugin url_launcher](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/url_launcher) and other examples from the flutter team. It greatly helped me creating a plugin for each respectful platform.

I found that "implements:" is no more than an [indicating](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#federated-platform-packages) with no technical effect.

The documentation says

"*Federated platform packages
A platform package uses the same format, but includes an implements entry **indicating** which app-facing package it is an implementation for. For example, a hello_windows plugin containing the Windows implementation for hello would have the following flutter: map:*"

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with the official flutter doc for 2 days, then I found the cli that generates plugin with 2 lines of commands

https://github.com/VeryGoodOpenSource/very_good_flutter_plugin

The lesson learn is never waste time with instruction that doesn't match with example source code.